# Can I mount a gpt disk with ntfs partition on an mbr booted linux system

Tags: mount, ntfs, gpt, mbr

System: Linux Mint 20 x64 cinnamon booted on mbr formatted disk.

I inserted a new hdd containing a gpt and a ntfs partition (next to a small MSR partition, which doesn't matter here I guess). GParted detects the hdd but the **mount option is greyed out**. Why is that? And what can I do to mount this partition?

Comment: Gpt is not the issue. If Windows NTFS, then you may have Windows fast start up on which sets hibernation flag. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1288661/windows-10-doesnt-start-after-setting-up-dual-boot-with-ubuntu-20-04/1288764#1288764 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: I just connected the disk to this system, it was before mounted in Windows10 on another system. I unmounted it in Windows Disk Manager before I disconnected it... But I did not shutdown the Windows system.

Comment: The fast startup/hibernation locks the NTFS partitions from access from another system. You have to change the settings. And Windows turns it back on with updates, so when you have issues again you have to boot Windows & turn it off. Normal shutdown leaves it hibernated. Or abnormal shutdown can corrupt it. Then it may need chkdsk or major repairs.

Answer (score 0):

Like suggested in the comments the problem was indeed the **hybernation flag**. The ntfs-3g driver cannot safely mount the ntfs disk as Windows is in a hybernation state. This article explains it perfectly: [all-explaining article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)

some possible solutions:

- if you have **access to Windows**: boot into windows and do a normal shutdown/restart, fast-boot in Win8/10 must be disabled. Boot in Linux and ntfs disk will be accessible.
- if you have **no access to Windows**: `ntfs-3g remove_hiberfile`, it completely deletes hiberfil.sys and will cause you to lose all unsaved information in the hibernated Windows programs. But your ntfs partition can be ounted again as rw. [here is how](https://superuser.com/questions/964402/is-there-anyway-to-unlock-hibernated-ntfs-partition)